# obtener value de @Html.DropDownList en actionresult a travez de formcollection MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

tengo un @Html.DropDownList que lleno con una lista List<> con datos ya definidos, el dropdown list esta dentro de un formulario que envio al controlador GuardarConfiguracion,
los datos los recupero pasandole como parametro al controlador FormCollection form pero no eh podido recuperar el valor que se ha seleccionado (texto de la opcion seleccionada) en el controlador, si lo hago de la forma var ValorDos = form["fuente"];, me obtiene el indice que el dropdownlist le da a cada opcion del ddl

```
            <div class="text-left col-md-4">
                <label class="col-sm-12 control-label" for="email-03">Tipo de fuente:</label>
                @Html.DropDownList("fuente", ViewBag.TiposFuente as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control", id = "TipoFuente", name = "TipoFuente" })                                    
                <br />
            </div>
```

action result

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GuardarConfiguracion(FormCollection form)
    {

        List<clsTipoFuente> LstTiposFuente;
        LstTiposFuente = new List<clsTipoFuente>();
        clsTipoFuente TipoFuenteArial = new clsTipoFuente()
        {
            IdTipoFuente = 1,
            TipoFuente = "Arial",
        };
        LstTiposFuente.Add(TipoFuenteArial);
        clsTipoFuente TipoFuenteCalibri = new clsTipoFuente()
        {
            IdTipoFuente = 3,
            TipoFuente = "Calibri",
        };
        LstTiposFuente.Add(TipoFuenteCalibri);
        clsTipoFuente TipoFuenteTimes = new clsTipoFuente()
        {
            IdTipoFuente = 5,
            TipoFuente = "Times",
        };
        LstTiposFuente.Add(TipoFuenteTimes);

        ViewBag.TiposFuente = new SelectList(LstTiposFuente, "IdTipoFuente", "TipoFuente");


        var ValorUno = form["txtNombreLicitacion"];
        var ValorDos = form["fuente"];


        return View("Index");

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Como `ViewBag.Fuentes` es de tipo `SelectList`, entonces al momento de llenar el `SelectList`, asignarle el valor que quieres que el servidor reciba.

Por ejemplo cuando generas el `SelectList`, a los `SelectListItem` le especificas el texto(que es lo que quieres) a la propiedad `Value` y no el indice(o lo que se que le estes asignado).:

```
var item = new SelectListItem{
```

Texto = "El Texto", 
Value = <-- a esta propiedad es donde tienes que poner el valor quieres enviar al server
};

```
ViewBag.Fuentes = new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>(){ item });
```

Answer (score 0):

Quítale el 'id' y el 'name' a los htmlAttributes, con eso estas renombrando tu elemento html select-option, entonces en tu forma vienen con ese nombre:

```
<div class="text-left col-md-4">
    <label class="col-sm-12 control-label" for="email-03">Tipo de fuente:</label>
    @Html.DropDownList("fuente", ViewBag.TiposFuente as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
    <br />
</div>
```

O, en tu action method léelos con ese nombre:

```
var ValorDos = form["TipoFuente"];
```